# How do you check if your wifi is connected to 802.11ac vs n in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I dual-booted Linux mint on MacBook pro running macOS Catalina. I am getting 240 Mb/s down on macOS but only 30-40 down on Linux mint. I am connected to 802.11ac on macOS. How would I check if my connection in Linux is 802.11ac or not? and/fix the problem?

Comment: Hello there. Maybe this can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283352/how-can-i-find-if-my-wifi-card-supports-802-11ac

Comment: my wifi card does support 802.11ac on macOS. The hardware supports it. My how would I know the my current connection in linux is on ac network vs other.

Comment: That's a software command though. Using those commands in linux should tell you if Linux can detect the 802.11ac part of your wifi card. Just to say: 802.11ac just hates open-source OS.

Comment: I entered that command and the output shows it supports 802.11ac. Idk why I am not getting the speeds.

Answer (score 6):

Try `sudo iw wlan0 station dump`, where `wlan0` is your WLAN device. This will give you both the current transmission and receive rate and the channel width.

If your channel width is 80 MHz or 160 Mhz, you are using 802.11ac. If your channel width is 20 MHz or 40 MHz, you are using 802.11n.

Note that 802.11ac includes 802.11n as a fallback option, and depending on send/receive conditions, 802.11ac will scale back to 40 MHz or 20 MHz wide channels and lower bit rates. Then you are still "using 802.11ac".

If you want to see what your driver/hardware combination is capable of ("does it support 802.11ac in the first place?"), use `iw phy`. If you see `VHT` (very high througput), you have 802.11ac.

Also note that hardware support on the MacBook may be suboptimal for Apple specific hardware like the WLAN. So if `iw phy` doesn't show `VHT`, there's nothing you can do about it, unless you can get Apple to make their hardware documentation public so people can write Linux drivers for it.

Comment: So if you have 802.11ac but only use 40 MHz channel width, does that mean it is _exactly_ the same as using 802.11n?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because you will (at that time) transfer data as if you were using 802.11n. No, because in the next second your neighbour could switch off his WLAN, and your hardware could decide to use the 80 MHz width channel, which won't work in 802.11n. Anyhow, if the problem is that you are seeing actual differences in download speed, measured by the application, on several occasions so it's unlikely your neighbour only switches on his WLAN if you use Mint, then it's likely that it's a driver problem.

Comment: @dirkt I see VHT so I got 802.1ac but to check if my connection is running on that I typed `sudo iw wlan0 station dump` it just give a list of man page I think. should be replacing wlan0 with something?

Comment: Yes, you should replace `wlan0` with the name of your WLAN device, as I wrote in the answer: "where `wlan0` is your WLAN device.". Use `sudo iw dev` to get a list of physical devices with associated WLAN devices, or `ip link` to get a list of all network devices, including WLAN.

Comment: @dirkt Okay, thanks. My hardware supports 802.11ac and for brief time I did get the speeds of 802.11ac to I just think it's a driver issue.